# Can I retrieve an authenticated RSS feed with YQL?

Tags: authentication, rss, yql

I want to retrieve the contents of an RSS feed via YQL:
http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/

The RSS feed is protected with basic authentication - username & password.  How can I pass the username and password in the YQL console to gain access to the feed?

Simon

Answer (score 0):

For basic auth you can provide login and password in url: http://username:password@rssfeed.com/url

Details are described in [RFC 2617](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2617.txt)